# this.Cursor not working properly?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project to take control of the mouse, and in the following code, i'm a little lost.

I declare the namespaces needed for the objects:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
```

and in the code here:

```
this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
```

it tells me that Cursor doesn't exist in the context, but only in `this.Cursor`. Same applies for `this.Loc` and `this.Size`. Anyone know why? Am I missing a namespace?

EDIT: Exact code:

```
public class MouseMove
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] //TODO add block feature on screens that need it
    private static extern bool BlockInput(bool block);

    public static void Main()
    {
        this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
        Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide method and class where this code is written?

Comment: Does your class have a field named `Cursor`?

Answer (score 1):

[Position](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip(v=vs.110).aspx) is a static property of `Cursor`. You can not access them with an instance. In order to use static variable you need to use following syntax : `classname.variablename`. In your case code should be similar to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(location, size);
}
```

As I consider, you took an example from MSDN, but in the example there are a WinForm application with form that has a cursor - `this.Cursor`. 
And on `Cursor.Position` line  `Cursor` is a class name, not an instance.

```
private void MoveCursor()
{
   //here Cursor is a form's property 
   this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle); 
   // here Cursor is a class name, Position is a static variable.
   Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - 50, Cursor.Position.Y - 50); 
   // here Cursor is a class name, Clip is a static variable.
   Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is replacing the system's cursor with itself...

I suggest something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Cursor myCursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    myCursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y);
    myCursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
}
```

That way it's safe. But even then, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: You can't call `myCursor` in `Main()` because `myCursor` is not static

Comment: It's just for a tutorial stage in the game I'm making, which manipulates the cursor for you. All I'm trying to accomplish is make it move where I want it to. I'll give this a try, thanks

Comment: @TAYLORBROWN: I changed it a bit. Since you just want to move it around you don't need to perpetuate the existence of your Cursor object so I made it local. Make sure you get the basics of what declaration, instantiation, classes, and objects mean, to help you on your path to learning. I hope you enjoy your discoveries!

Comment: @MPelletier Have you run it? As I consider, you can't change static variables with an instance.